# Couchbase & nodejs: View query with total number of rows

Tags: node.js, couchbase

Hi I would like to inform the client if there are more rows in database that match a query running on a view.

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var ViewQuery = couchbase.ViewQuery;
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(config);
var bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName, password); 
var query = ViewQuery.from('items', 'by_criteria').key('mykey').limit(limit).skip(offset); 
bucket.query(query, function (err, result, meta) {
// the meta here has a total_rows which is number of rows indexed in the view. 
}
```

The 'meta' has a total_rows which is number of rows indexed in the view and not ones that match the query. So no matter what you put in your query it always returns the same value.